# using both server and client side rendering using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to front end development. I want to build a basic app which utilises both server side and client side rendering. I am using nodejs for server side rendering. I am not sure why i am unable to render the html along with the javascript file (externally linked with HTML)

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Display Time and Date </title>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p id="dat"></p>
<p id="time"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DisplayDate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

DisplayDate.js:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hours = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
if (min < 10) min = '0' + min;
document.getElementById("dat").innerHTML = "Today\'s Date: " + day +"/" + month + "/" + year ;
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time: " + hours + ":" + min; }
```

index.js: -> (server side rendering this file)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function(err, data) { 
if(err) {
res.write('ERROR')
}
else {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write(data);
}

res.end();
});
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
console.log('server-side rendering working fine');
```

Comment: Are you able to load html file without javascript?

Comment: you can you use express framework, to render the html files

Comment: @PavanVora yes i can load the html. My problem is i am seeing only the header (h1) and not any of the paragraphs whose value is set by DisplayDate.js

Comment: Because you just return html content, you can open developer tool of browser, a error has been appeared `http://localhost:8080/DisplayDate.js` not found.

Comment: @BhauraoBirajdar is it possible to render html along with javascript without using any frameworks ? Also is my understanding correct regarding the server and client side rendering?

Comment: @hoangdv i am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". Also all the above files are in my git repository and i am using heroku to deploy them. 
https://anime-nation.herokuapp.com/ - > is the link 

what should i do to render the page along with the javascript present inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it won't work because you are sending plain text it is static data.
you have only 2 ways
1. using Express JS it has `res.sendFile()` method it will take care about linking of files
2. place your JS code inside html page

you have one more way but it is not recommended

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display Time and Date </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p id="dat"></p>
        <p id="time"></p>
        <script>
            function loadFile(filename){
                var script=document.createElement('script')
                script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
                $.get(filename, (data)=>{
                   script.innerText = data
                   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
               }) //use AJAX to get your JS code and place it inside new script element you can use XMLHttpRequest i am using JQUERY here

            }       
            loadFile("DisplayDate.js")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```